# Core dump file name truncated

Tags: linux, coredump

Given the configuration in `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` set to `/cores/core.%e.%p`, core dumps are named according to pattern, however for processes running executables with long names e.g. `SampleCrashApplication`, the generated core file will contain a truncated executable name: `/cores/core.SampleCrashAppl.9933`

What is causing this ? The `man core` page talks only about maximum size of the resulting core filename being 128 (64 for kernels before 2.6.19)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for this can be found in exec.c [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc#_8sx1eKpw2w/linux-2.6.1/fs/exec.c&q=core_pattern%20lang:c&l=1202).

The code is going to copy the corename based on the pattern up to the first percentage (giving /cores/core.).  At the percentage it's going to increment and process the 'e'.  The code for processing the 'e' part prints out the pattern using snprintf based on the current->comm structure.

This is the executable name (excluding path) TRUNCATED to the value [TASK_COMM_LEN](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=2&ct=rc#3C3saXwSWsQ/trunk/linux-2.6.24.3/include/linux/sched.h&q=TASK_COMM_LEN%20lang:c%20linux&l=203).  Since this is defined as 16 characters (at least in the Kernel I found) then SampleCrashApplication is truncated to 15 + 1 characters (1 for the null byte at the end) which explains why you get your truncated core dump name.

At to why this structure truncates the name TASK_COMM_LEN, that's a deeper question, but it's something internal to the kernel and there's some discussion [here](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0606.2/2942.html).